# Mysql deadlocks using multiple queued jobs in Laravel Supervisor

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, supervisord

I need to import simultaneously the data from 55 .tsv files into **MySQL Database**.

I have the job that reads the file and updates the rows on database using the ***updateOrCreate()*** method.

**My Supervisor config:**

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /Users/denis/Code/my_project/artisan queue:work --tries=3 --timeout=3600 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=55
stdout_logfile=/Users/denis/Code/my_project/storage/logs/workers.log
stderr_logfile=/Users/denis/Code/my_project/storage/logs/workers_error.log
```

But when I do it, all the jobs fails with the error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock
>   found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction in
>   /Users/denis/Code/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:474
>   ...

I can resolve it with try-catch block

```
$updated = null;
$db_max_retries = 10;
$db_retry_count = 0;
while($updated == null && $db_retry_count < $db_max_retries) {
    try {
        $updated = AdsPerformance::updateOrCreate(['campaign_id' => $performance_obj['campaign_id'], 'date' => $performance_obj['date'], 'ad_provider' => 'adwords'], $performance_obj);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        sleep(1);
        $db_retry_count++;
    }
}
$lines_proceded++;
```

... but in this case the process takes very long time, as there are ~200 deadlocks in ~2000 imported lines.

- **When the table is empty, there is no deadlocks. Deadlocks only appear when the table already has the data (Basically when trying to update)**
- I tried to use different sleep times. With the sleep=5, there are less deadlocks. With sleep=1/10 seconds (i used *usleep(100000)*) there are more deadlocks. Btw the total execution time is not very different in these cases.
- I tried to use other **queue drivers (redis and beanstalkd)**. But there is also not the big difference.

Maybe there is some other solution I can try? Like some MySQL configuration or something else? I don't believe there is no solution to make simultaneous updates without deadlocks in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just realise that the problem was using composite primary key. 
To solve it, I created unique primary key column with concatenated primary keys and there are no more deadlocks.